# Accessing and manipulating the values ( in list form) of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with keys and a list attached as value to each key.
I have to traverse list value attached to each key and segregate them into two different lists with '0' and '1' ( as '0' and '1' are the values in the list) also with the count of '0' , '1' and the total. Please let me know how should i go abut doing this. Thanks

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the output that you would like.  It's not completely clear what you want.

Comment: Given: dictionary = {K1:[0,1,1,0,1,0,0], K2:[1,1,1,0,0,1,1], K3:[0,0,0,1,1,1,0]}

Comment: I have to go through the values of each K1, K2 and K3 may be using a for loop and using 'if' inside that have to check whether its '1' or '0' and then put them in different lists.

Comment: Plus meanwhile get the count of '1' and '0' and total in each value of each key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#to loop through a dictionary
total_0 = 0
list_0 =[]
total_1 = 0
list_1 = []
somedict = {'key1':[1,1,1,0,1,0]}
for key,value in somedict.items():
    # now loop through each list of your dict, since value keep your list
    for item in value:
        if item == 1: 
            total_1 += 1
            list_1.append(item)
        else : 
            total_0 += 1
            list_0.append(item)
```

Thats an example, if you explain it with detail, i will try to help you more (:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is abundantly under-specified (are the two different lists supposed to be mutually exclusive?  What happens if a key has a list with both `0` and `1`, or neither?  Etc).  But if for example there is no mutual exclusion constraint, the counts must count each 0 or 1 repeatedly if it occurs repeatedly, and many other guesses about conditions you just don't mention at all...:

```
def weird_op(d):
  keysw0 = []
  keysw1 = []
  count0s = count1s = 0
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    n0 = v.count('0')
    n1 = v.count('1')
    if n0: keysw0.append(k)
    if n1: keysw1.append(k)
    count0s += n0
    count1s += n1
  return keysw0, keysw1, count0s, count1s
```

I've omitted the "also the total" part of your request because, for **that** one, the lack of specs borders on the nightmare -- total of **WHAT**?!  Keys, items in the lists, angels dancing on the point of a pin...?!  And since you very specifically mention that the lists' items are strings (you *do* use quotes around them, which must mean strings -- right...?) how the flip do you propose to "total" them?!

If you can clarify the specs (especially that weird "total" one!) no doubt better approaches can be found, but this is the boundary to which my mind-reading patented crystal ball can push.  BTW, as part of the specs, some examples of input dict-of-lists and expected results for each would really really help.

Comment: 1) Each key would for sure have both '1' and '0'.

Comment: 2) Yes the counter is expected to count the number of '0' and '1' it encounters

Comment: 3) Although the values would be string, I here, by total mean the total number of both '0' and '1' it has encountered

Comment: @Comp, given these clarifications my code should be what you require (i.e. looks like I guessed luckily), with the addition of `count0s + count1s` to "total" them (surely you _do_ know that the `+` operator applied to two numbers "totals" them, right?  so since you _were_ already requesting the count of 0s and of 1s, certainly you can't consider it a problem to "total" those two counts...?!  which is part of why it hadn't even crossed my mind that the super-mysterious bit of the spec would be just about summing two numbers you've already computed...!!!).